# Add Style to DropDown React native

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, github, react-native

I add [this](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-dropdown) plugin 
and try to draw the Dropdown, it works fine 
in this way

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-start',alignSelf:'center', backgroundColor:'#ebeef0'}}>
          <Select style={{  alignItems: 'flex-start' }}
            width={250}
            ref="SELECT1"
            optionListRef={this._getOptionList.bind(this)}
            defaultValue="Select One of Option ..."
            onSelect={this._canada.bind(this)}>
            <Option>First</Option>
            <Option>Second</Option>
            <Option>Third</Option>
            <Option>Forth</Option>
            <Option>Fifth</Option>
            <Option>Six</Option>
            <Option>Seven</Option>
            <Option>Eight</Option>
            <Option>Ten</Option>
            <Option>Eleven</Option>
            <Option>Twelve</Option>
          </Select>          

          <OptionList ref="OPTIONLIST"/>
      </View>
```

What I need ,to make it looks like the asp.net dropdown with arrow 
as
[image]

At least I want to know how to change the style of the Dropdown how can I override the style of the installed plugin.